# Implementation of an AUTOSAR NM sequence diagram

Tags: automotive, can

[image: NM Sequence diagram]

I am planning to implement the CAN NM as per the above sequence diagram. My understanding of the diagram is as follows. A Message Cycle Timer will be running continuously which is a configurable parameter. Once it expires, I call the function `CanIf_Transmit(Std_ReturnType, PduIdType, const PduInfoType*)`.

The next step is the dotted line with function `CanIf_Transmit()`. The question here is: It is showing as empty arguments, but actually it contains arguments; then why does it show as empty arguments? Similarly for `CanNm_TxConfirmation(PduIdType, E_OK)`. Why is it so? What is the significance of the dotted lines?

[Autosar CAN NM](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-3/AUTOSAR_SWS_CANNetworkManagement.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> The next step is the dotted line with function CanIf_Transmit(), the
>   doubt here is it is showing as empty arguments but actually it
>   contains arguments. Then why does it show as empty arguments?
>   Similarly for CanNm_TxConfirmation(PduIdType, E_OK). Why is it so?
>   What is the significance of dotted lines?

The diagram in your image is called a [sequence diagram](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Sequence_diagram).

The solid line represents a *method/function call* and the dotted line represents the *response/return* for that function.

In your example, `CanIf_Transmit()` is just showing the return of the `CanIf_Transmit(Std_ReturnType, PduIdType, const PduInfoType*)` function call. There's no need to write the function parameters twice..